# Calculate sum of total fine and add fine when books is overdue

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I calculate a fine when the books are still not returned after the given due date? I do want to add a penalty of 5 every day if the book is still not returned.

I have tried so far

```
public void CalculateFine()
{
  DateTime dueDate = new DateTime();
  DateTime returnDate = new DateTime();
  dueDate = frmissue.dtDueDate.Value;
  returnDate = DateTime.Now;
  TimeSpan diff = returnDate.Subtract(dueDate);
  int days = diff.Days;
  fine = days * 5;

  cn.Open();
  cm = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tblFine VALUES (@borrowID, @studentID, @totalFine)", cn);
  cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@borrowID", lblID.Text);
  cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studentID", lblStudentID.Text);
  cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@totalFine", fine);
  cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
  cn.Close();
}
```

It works for me when I click the return book button, but if there is no overdue fine, when I return books even before the due date it also calculates and inserts fine something like  **-35**  in my column totalFine. I don't want to have a negative value, instead, I want to have 0 value if the books are returned on or before the given due date.

I have tried to search and can't fully understand some of it since I am new to programming.

Comment: I have to ask… “where” in the posted code are you trying to _”have 0 value if the books is returned on or before the given due date.”_ … I do not see “where” you are “comparing” the time difference. I can see that `diff` is the “difference” between the dates, however, you don’t check this value. The code simply gets the number of days from `diff` and multiplies it by 5 for the fine. Where are you checking to see if `days` value is zero or greater than zero or less than 0?

Comment: @JohnG I store the total fine to my tblFine so I can sum it all and gets to show the pending payment/fine to a label. I don't really get your question, i'm sorry

Comment: I am saying that on the line of code… `int days = diff.Days;` … you get the number of days between the two dates. If `days` = 0, then the dates are the same dates. If `days` is “less than 0” then the `dueDate` is greater than the `returnedDate`. Your code “never” checks this `days` value. If `days` is less than zero it will produce a negative number when multiplied by 5. Your code is not checking this and this appears to be what you are asking. If you want negative numbers to be 0, then “check” what value `days` is and if less than zero, then set it 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(fine < 0)
{
    fine = 0;
}
```

just add these codes before cn.Open();